# Polynomials that often gives primes

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Consider $P^f_n=|\{m<n|f(m)\in\mathbb P\}|$, where $f$ is a strictly increasing function $\mathbb N^+\to \mathbb N^+$. Below a diagram of $P^f_n$ for different functions $f$:

[image]

(Are there polynomials $q$ which are strictly increasing on $\mathbb N^+$ such that $P^q_n>>P^u_n$, where $u(n)=2n-1$?)

> Changed question:
>   Is there an upper bound strictly less than $p_n$?
>   Is there an optimal polynomial of degree 1?

---

I first believed that the polynomial $n\curvearrowright k!\cdot n+1$ would give larger $P^f_n$ for increasing $k$, which isn't true. The most high density polynomial I found so far is $n\curvearrowright 30n-7$

Comment: I can prove that that there does $\textbf{not}$ exist a linear function $f$ such that for all lineair functions $g$ and all positive integers $n,m$ greater than some threshold $N$ we have $$\frac{P^f_n}{n}>\frac{P^g_m}{m}$$. Would that prove there is no optimal polynomial of degree one, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @Mastrem: that would be nice to see as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a linear function $f$ such that for all linear functions $g$ and all $n,m>N$ for some integer $N$ we have
$$\frac{P^f_n}{n}\ge\frac{P^g_m}{m}$$

---

Write $f(x)=ax+b$. Now, for all positive integers $n>N$ ($m$ is also assumed to be integer)
$$\{0<m<bn:am+b\text{ is prime}\}=\bigcup_{i=0}^{b-1}\{0<m<n:abm+ai+b\text{ is prime}\}$$
On the right side there are $b$ sets. However, the one with $i=0$ does not contain any primes, which means there is at least one $0\le k\le b-1$ such that
$$\{0<m<n:abm+ak+b\}$$
contains more than $\frac 1b P^f_{bn}$ primes. Defining $g(x)=abx+ak+b$ gives:
$$\frac1bP^f_{bn}<P^g_n$$
dividing both sides by $n$ yields:
$$\frac{P^f_{bn}}{bn}<\frac{P^g_n}{n}$$
which contradicts our earlier statement about $f$, meaning that there does **not** exist a linear function $f$ such that for all linear functions $g$ and natural numbers $n,m$ larger than some constant $N$ we have
$$\frac{P^f_n}{n}\ge\frac{P^g_m}{m}$$